How to decide between using the SharePoint folder vs web connector to access excel file?
I have few csv and excel files in SharePoint.
I want to access them in power bi. On what basis do I decide between using the power bi sharpeoint folder connector or the power bi web connector.

With SharePoint folder connector, you will only have the one credentials to maintain, whereas with Web connector, you will have credentials per file to maintain.
Web connector is faster as you are going direct to one file. SharePoint folder connector is more robust of the two if you are loading more than a couple of files from the same SharePoint folder.

Is there a way to access it using app registration or service account, rather than on behalf of the dataset developer?

Via Service Account, yes.

Where do I input this service account when configuring?

Have a look at Create and share cloud data sources in the Power BI service

This works for database. But not for SharePoint which is the question about.

Have you tried it? The link is showing the example of a SQL connection, there are other options in there... https://i.sstatic.net/Ws0myAwX.png and looks like you can use Service Principal now (app registration). Finally, don't you think you are moving off topic to your original question?
